# When I met her in June

Tags: music

> You know, I had a girlfriend once.
>
> I met her in June, following the sound of my heartbeat.
>
> We became deeper in love, as the seasons changed, from summer to fall.
>
> I knew that we'd be together as long as the skies remained their color, till the ends of the Earth.
>
> But then she did something. Something bad.
>
> She acts innocent, like nothing happened. And yet she told that lie so quickly.

This little story was put together by the author. The way the lines are spoken refrences a song that him and his lover used to listen to.

What song is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The song is

> Summer by Calvin Harris

Lyrics:

> When I met you in the summer
> To my heartbeat sound  
> We fell in love  
> As the leaves turned brown  
>  And we could be together baby  
> As long as skies are blue 
>  You act so innocent now  
> But you lied so soon

Comment: I thought I hid that better. Hm...

Comment: No worries, I just happened to know most of the lyrics to that song haha

Comment: OK then. I'm working on a slightly better follow-up question.