# She came back and tried to apologize

Tags: music

After a man [broke up with his girlfriend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30530/18770), he hid the details in a song.

Now she's come back, this time with a hidden message of her own.

> hi eVan
>
> look i waNna cHAnge tHiNgs between us just mE and you eVan
>
> thiNgs may sEem baD but I know yOu and i can get through this sTuff oK?
>
> mY old lieS are tHE texts shown here:
>
> > i'M nOt coming tonigHt, i'M feeling sick.
>
> > sorRy i misseD tonigHt, i rEAlly feel tErriBle. i have a headacHe and i rEally think yOu shouldn't come over toniGht
>
> > hey dONT botHer coming wIth aNYtHing for tHe party toNight, lAura had to take care oF sOme stuff at heR place
>
> can yOU uNderstand? i'm sorry.

Evan asked her:

> What's with the capitalization?

His ex replied:

> Oh that's part of the encrypted message, since I know you're a Puzzling.SE member :) It was supposed to be different, but the program had- ah, what's that error programmers talk about all the time? Not the semicolon thing, but something else...

> Yeah, OK. What are you trying to say?

> Well, there's a song I've hidden in my message... it's what I'm asking of you.

> And why should I trust you?

> Look, just find the song, OK?

Then he found the song.

> This... this is what you want me to do?

> Yeah.

> All right... meet me for coffee, we can talk there.

Everything worked out well.

But there's one thing that still bothers me:

**What song did she use to get him to talk to her?**

Comment: love the programming reference.  I was like dub tee eff? OHHHHH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The song is:

> Forgive me by Evanescence, because when you take the letter before the capitalized ones it spells: "Each time i say something I regret I cry: 'I don’t want to lose you!'"

Comment: Ooh, first by less than 10 seconds!  Great work to both you and @question_asker!

Comment: @feelinferrety Yeah that was really close haha :D

Comment: @feelinferrety funny story about that...

Comment: @question_asker Oh?

Answer (score 6):

It's

> *Forgive Me*, by Evanescence

because

> The capitalized letters are *off by one* - if you take one letter before each capitalized letter (including some already capitalized), you get *'Each time I say something I regret I cry "I don't want to lose you."'*